# R will not loop over dates correctly - reinterprets as not a date

Tags: r, loops, date, for-loop

R will read as a date, and will interpret it correctly as a date. I am trying to figure out for my data how many rows have duplicate dates.

```
test <- as.Date(final_data$DateCancelled, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
dd <- subset(test, test >= "2016-07-01")
length(which(dd=="2016-07-01"))
```

Whatever date I fill in on length(which()), it will correctly return the number of rows that have that date for the $DateCancelled var.

However, whenever I try to for loop this, it will will not read it as a date. For instance:

```
for (d in dd) {
+     print(d)
+ }
```

Returns these "dates"

```
[1] 17009
[1] 17009
[1] 17009
[1] 16988
[1] 16989
[1] 17009
[1] 16996
[1] 16996
```

Why does it re-interpret this into something that is clearly not a date? I'm not really exactly sure what it is interpreting it as.

EDIT #1: I should clarify, what I really want to do is loop over the

```
length(which(date=="2016-07-01")
```

above, and have it loop over every date in dd. I want it to loop over and tell me for each date, how many rows have that date in the $DateCancelled variable.

Comment: `17009` == `2016-07-27` - have a look at `?Date`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi this will now print dates, but what I really want is to combine the for loop with the following: "length(which(dd="2016-07-01")", where the date is what's being looped over. When i try to combine it with the for loop provided above, it prints instead just the # of that row which it appears on.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi edited parent post above.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I have tried while loops, but have had a similar issue. I am going to do other things with this later too, so would prefer to do this as a for loop rather than while. Also I want it to loop over each date, not just "2016-07-01", i just put that in there as an example.

Comment: If you just want to know for each date how many were canceled, use `table(dd$DateCanceled)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
### first create some sample data that looks like final_data$DateCancelled

sample_dates<-append(seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'),as.Date('2016-01-10'),by = 1), 
                 seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'),as.Date('2016-01-03'),by = 1)
                 )

### find the unique values that exist and put them in a list

unique_dates<-list(dates=unique(sample_dates))

###loop through each value of date within the original data set which in this case is "sample_dates" and output counts to "unique_dates" list

for(i in 1:length(unique_dates$dates)){

unique_dates$counts[[i]]<-length(subset(sample_dates,
                                        sample_dates==unique_dates$dates[[i]]))

    }

### format output as data frame
final_output<-data.frame(unique_dates)

> final_output
        dates counts
1  2016-01-01      2
2  2016-01-02      2
3  2016-01-03      2
4  2016-01-04      1
5  2016-01-05      1
6  2016-01-06      1
7  2016-01-07      1
8  2016-01-08      1
9  2016-01-09      1
10 2016-01-10      1
```